# Prove that |tA| = |t| |A| where A ⊆ R, t ∈ R, | · | is outer measure. But why don't both sides equal 0 always?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, outer-measure

This exercise comes from: Sheldon Axler's "Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis". Section 2A, Exercise 2.

I have read the answers to the following, and understand the proofs.

(1)[$A\subset\mathbb{R}, t\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow |tA|=|t||A|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4081687/a-subset-mathbbr-t-in-mathbbr-rightarrow-ta-ta)

(2)[Analysis question on outer measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820523/analysis-question-on-outer-measure)

Nevertheless I cannot figure out why the following reasoning is wrong:

---

(Note: $tA$ is defined as $\{ta | a \in A\}$)

Finite sets have outer measure $0$. Since $t$ is a single element, $t$ has outer measure $0$. Therefore, $$|t||A| = 0 |A| = 0.$$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $A \in \mathbb{R}$.

Yet, in the case that $t = 1$, with $A$ being any open interval of $\mathbb{R}$, we have that

$$|tA| = \{1a | a \in A\} = |A|$$

Thus,

$$ 0 = |t||A| \neq |tA| = A $$

So the statement that $|t||A| = |tA|$ is false.

Why am I wrong? Thank you.

Comment: hi sloth. $|t|$ means the absolute value of $t$ here, and not the outer measure of $\{t\}$ (which would be written $|\{t\}|$ and not $|t|$)

Comment: Thanks @AtticusStonestrom... that cleared everything up. It was not clear to me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|t|$ is absolute value of $t\in\Bbb{R}$ .
Can you prove that $|t|=\lambda^{*}(\{t\})$?

$\lambda^{*}$ : Lebesgue outer measure.

$\lambda^{*}(tA) =|t|\lambda^{*}(A)$

no danger of confusion.